# Changing the size of 1D and 2D variable length array

Tags: c, c99, c11

With the inclusion of Variable length arrays, in C99 & next versions, the following program works.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int i, numFibs;
    printf ("How many Fibonacci numbers do you want (between 1 and 75)? ");
    scanf ("%i", &numFibs);
    if (numFibs < 1 || numFibs > 75) 
    {
        printf ("Bad number, sorry!\n");
        return 1;
    }
    unsigned long long int   Fibonacci[numFibs];
    Fibonacci[0] = 0;          // by definition
    Fibonacci[1] = 1;          // ditto
    for ( i = 2;  i < numFibs;  ++i )
    {
        Fibonacci[i] = Fibonacci[i-2] + Fibonacci[i-1];
    }
    for ( i = 0;  i < numFibs;  ++i )
    {
        printf ("%llu  ", Fibonacci[i]);
        printf ("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

But when i try to implement the following program, it works fine till a<=9, any value of a>9 the program does not take more than 9 elements in the array.

Why?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int a=0;
    int arr[a];
    printf("Enter number of rows: ");
    scanf("%d", &a);
    printf("\nNo of rows to be entered: %d\n", a);
    for(int j=0; j<a; j++)
    {
        printf("Enter array element[%d]: ", j);
        scanf("%d", &arr[j]);
    }
    for(int j=0; j<a; j++)
    {
        printf("Entered array element [%d]: %d", j, arr[j]);
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Below is an example for a 2D array, which works fine till Value of b<=2, post that program ends up in a segmentation failure.  Why ?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int b=0;
    int arr[b][2];
    printf("Enter number of rows: ");
    scanf("%d", &b);
    printf("No of rows to be entered: %d", b);
    for(int i=0; i<b; i++)
    {
        for(int j=0; j<2; j++)
        {
            printf("Enter array element[%d][%d]: ", i, j);
            scanf("%d", &arr[i][j]);
        }
    }
    printf("\n");
    for(int i=0; i<b; i++)
    {
        for(int j=0; j<2; j++)
        {
            printf("Enter array element[%d][%d]: %d", i, j, arr[i][j]);
            printf("\n");
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

In above example taking both row and columns dynamically will be wrong but, taking rows dynamically works. if you take columns dynamically it will fail as well.

is there any other way to solve these problems without malloc()?

GCC version running on machine:-

> C:\Users\gahlot>gcc -v Using built-in specs. COLLECT_GCC=gcc
>   COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=c:/mingw/bin/../libexec/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/lto-wrapper.exe Target: mingw32 Configured with: ../src/gcc-6.3.0/configure
>   --build=x86_64-pc-linux-gnu --host=mingw32 --target=mingw32 --with-gmp=/mingw --with-mpfr --with-mpc=/mingw --with-isl=/mingw --prefix=/mingw --disable-win32-registry --with-arch=i586 --with-tune=generic --enable-languages=c,c++,objc,obj-c++,fortran,ada --with-pkgversion='MinGW.org GCC-6.3.0-1' --enable-static --enable-shared --enable-threads --with-dwarf2 --disable-sjlj-exceptions --enable-version-specific-runtime-libs --with-libiconv-prefix=/mingw --with-libintl-prefix=/mingw --enable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-libgomp --disable-libvtv --enable-nls Thread model: win32 gcc version 6.3.0 (MinGW.org GCC-6.3.0-1)

Comment: I’m pretty sure that’s not how VLA’s work. I don’t think they change size. Only allow you to declare the array after you know the size. Your second and third examples are creating arrays with a size of 0

Comment: In first example, i am changing the size of the array as well. numFibs is the size of the array which is set by the user.

Comment: In 3rd example taking both row and columns dynamically will be wrong but, taking rows dynamically works. if you take columns dynamically it will fail as well.

Comment: No in the first example you are declaring Fibonacci after you know numFibs. From then on it is that size. Similarly if you malloc’ed it it would be the size you malloc’ed until you realloc’ed

Comment: So if i declare array after the input of size of array then it should work? Hmm seems interesting let me check.

Comment: Move you `int arr...` to below your first `scanf` and see

Comment: yep it's workin now @MDK,

Comment: Excellent !!!!!

Comment: No in the first example you are declaring Fibonacci after you know numFibs. From then on it is that size. Similarly if you malloc’ed it it would be the size you malloc’ed until you realloc’ed. 

Okay can you explain why it does not update in the array if i put this at the top ??

Comment: It’s just not how they work. I think the only major Difference between VLAs and malloc is whether the variable is stored on the stack or heap. Either method at some point you put a size on it and reserve that much memory. In languages like C++ there are containers to handle truly dynamic but the do so by allocating chunks at a time

Comment: Yes now whether you change row or column it works fine in the 3rd example as well.

So, C99 or C11, it doesn't matter. Memory needs to be blocked before initialization. right ?

Comment: Oddly enough this is a common FAQ. We might have to come up with a canonical dupe for these kind of questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This doesn't do what you think it does:

```
int a=0;
int arr[a];
printf("Enter number of rows: ");
scanf("%d", &a);
```

Once an array is defined with a given size, even if that size is not a constant expression, the size of the array is fixed.  The size is **not** tied to the current value of `a`.  It is also not valid to create an array of size 0.

This is spelled out in section 6.7.6.2p5 of the C standard:

> If  the  size  is  an  expression  that  is  not  an  integer 
>   constant  expression:  if  it  occurs  in  a declaration at function
>   prototype scope, it is treated as if it were replaced by
>   * ; otherwise, **each time it is evaluated it shall have a value greater than zero.  The size of each instance of  a  variable  length  array 
>   type  does  not  change  during  its  lifetime.**

In this case, the size of the array is specified by a single variable, however the size can be determined by any expression.  For example:

```
int f()
{
    int a, b, c;
    scanf("%d", &a);
    b=3;
    c=9;
    return sqrt(a) * (b - c) + sin(b);
}

...

int arr[f()];
```

If you defined `arr` like this, even if you could change the size how would you expect that to happen?

As for why your second and third pieces of code sometimes works and sometimes doesn't, that means you're invoking [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).  In both cases, that's caused by creating an array where at least one dimension is 0 and subsequently attempting to use it.

Answer (score 1):

The size of a VLA is determined at the point where the declaration is encountered.

- You can't change their size afterwards
- The size expression must not have the value `0` or even be negative.

Comment: Explaination of this in detail like why it is like that will be very helpful. Or just should i consider C is just built like that??

Comment: If the declaration is early it still kind of works. this is kind of weird it should have failed instead of working for some values.  What do you think about that?

Comment: @Gahlot `int n[0]; n[1] = 123;` might _appear_ to work, but in fact it exhibits _undefined behaviour_ (google that term). Undefined behaviour includes "apparently working fine".

Comment: @Gahlot ... and yes, C works like this. Anyway how would you change the size of a VLA?

Comment: I was thinking the same if you could change the size in C like how i was trying to then why do you need anything else like malloc() ? 

So wanted to know the "why" behind this.